# What are the disadvantages of using $firebaseObject?

Tags: javascript, object, memory, firebase

I am using $firebaseObject in angularJS. I have a package dict. If I make a firebase object for package dict reference and call it..does it eats up the memory?

```
var pkgObj=$firebaseObject(Pkg_ref);
```

Now in my program I use:

```
var Pkg=pkgObj[140654060001];
```

This will give me Package details of package with package id 140654060001. `Pkg_ref` contains various package details with key as package id and value as package details(address, name, pincode etc).

Now if I again use

```
 Pkg=pkgObj[140654070003]
```

Does it eat up the memory or increase transactions?

Answer (score 1):

Having multiple references to the same location in the database uses up a minimal amount of extra memory. Typically it is not worth optimizing for that.

All references to the Firebase database use the same connection to get data from the server. If you have multiple references to the same location, the data (and updates to that data) will be transferred only once.

Comment: Your question is incredibly hard to understand, which is why I give you some broad information on how Firebase works. If you provide a single, [complete, minimal verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (code+data+expected behavior+actual behavior), I can try to provide a better answer. Consider setting up a working jsfiddle that shows your problem/concern.